# Get radiobutton value in javascript

Tags: javascript, primefaces

My code is below:
`<p:selectOneRadio value="#{myProgram1.selectedFlag}" id="radID">`
                `<f:selectItems value="#{myProgram1.flags}"/>`
            `</p:selectOneRadio>`
`<p:commandButton value="check"  onclick="check()"/>`

In my bean class the map flags is as below:

```
    `flags.put("1", "Apple");`
    `flags.put("2", "Boy");`
```

and my objective is to get the selected radio button value say if I select 1, then I should be able to get Apple in check() javascript function. My code is within a `h:form id="fid"`.
I have tried `document.getElementById("fid:radID")[0].checked` and `document.getElementById("fid:radID").value`. Nothing worked. Plz help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r" value="a">
```

by jQuery you can do like this

```
jQuery('#r').click(function(){
            var abc = this.value;
            alert(abc);
        })
```

Comment: Thanks Osama for your reply. But I am facing this problem particularly in this primefaces case(p:selectOneRadio).

Comment: @user17.. If you have more radio button you can use like this jQuery('#r').click(function(){ replace to jQuery('input:radio').click(function(){

Answer (score 1):

It is easier if you use the widgetVar property

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{myProgram1.selectedFlag}" id="radID" widgetVar="selectVar">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myProgram1.flags}"/> 
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Then you could check values from javascript by using the variable:

```
selectVar.inputs[0].checked
selectVar.inputs[1].checked
selectVar.inputs[2].checked
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a group of radio buttons with the same name, you can get the value by iterating over the collection of same named buttons, e.g.

```
<form ...>
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="0" checked>0<br>
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="3">3<br>

  <input type="button" value="show value" onclick="
    var radios = this.form.foo;

    for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {

      if (radios[i].checked) {
        alert(radios[i].value);
      }
    }
  ">
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks RobG for your reply. But I am facing this problem particularly in this primefaces case(p:selectOneRadio).

Comment: Missed the primefaces tag. I have no idea about that, post what you actually get in the browser (i.e. the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use name instead of id because element ID should be unique.
i modified your code in way to use element name to manage :

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{myProgram1.selectedFlag}" id="radID" name="programm[]">
<f:selectItems value="#{myProgram1.flags}"/> </p:selectOneRadio> <p:commandButton value="check" onclick="check()"/>
<script>
function check()
{
    var arrElements=document.getElementsByName('programm[]');
    $(arrElements).each(function(i,ele){
        if($(ele).attr('checked'))
        {
          /*Your application logic comes here*/
              /*To get Value of checked radio button use : ele.value */
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sarvesh. I have solved it and my approach is similar to that of yours. Thank u so much for sharing your thought.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks guys for your quality thoughts. I have solved it. the document.getElementsByName("fid:radID") returns a collection. by iterating it I m able to get checked radiobutton values.

Thanks sarvesh also. Yours method also worked well.